# Running npm install odbc in Sails app produces errors?

Tags: sails.js, unixodbc, node-odbc

I am trying to install the `node-odbc` package (https://github.com/wankdanker/node-odbc) in my Sails app.

As per the docs I have installed and configured unixobdc on the server but when I do **npm install odbc --save** in the app directory I get the following error:

> npm ERR! Linux 3.19.0-58-generic
>   npm ERR! argv "/usr/bin/nodejs" "/usr/bin/npm" "install" "odbc" "--save"
>   npm ERR! node v4.4.3
>   npm ERR! npm  v3.8.7
>
> npm ERR! Cannot set property 'waterline-criteria' of undefined
>   npm ERR!
>   npm ERR! If you need help, you may report this error at:
>   npm ERR!     *LINK{//github.com/npm/npm/issues}
>   npm ERR! Linux 3.19.0-58-generic
>   npm ERR! argv "/usr/bin/nodejs" "/usr/bin/npm" "install" "odbc" "--save"
>   npm ERR! node v4.4.3
>   npm ERR! npm  v3.8.7
>
> npm ERR! Cannot set property 'waterline-cursor' of undefined
>   npm ERR!
>   npm ERR! If you need help, you may report this error at:
>   npm ERR!     *LINK{//github.com/npm/npm/issues}
>   npm ERR! Linux 3.19.0-58-generic
>   npm ERR! argv "/usr/bin/nodejs" "/usr/bin/npm" "install" "odbc" "--save"
>   npm ERR! node v4.4.3
>   npm ERR! npm  v3.8.7
>
> npm ERR! Cannot set property 'waterline-errors' of undefined
>   npm ERR!
>   npm ERR! If you need help, you may report this error at:
>   npm ERR!     *LINK{//github.com/npm/npm/issues}
>
> npm ERR! Please include the following file with any support request:
>   npm ERR!     /var/www/sails.dev/secApp/npm-debug.log

Any ideas on why this is or how I could get this package to work in Sails?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

Delete the node_modules folder in your applications directory.

From within your applications directory run this command:

```
npm install odbc --save;
```

I suspect that something has gone wrong with your applications NPM installation so you are just refreshing it whilst adding your new package.